# Issue Passing Size Parameter from JavaScript to Django Backend

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-views

I'm encountering an issue with passing the "size" parameter from my JavaScript function to my Django backend. Here's the relevant code snippet from my Django view:

```py
def get_product(request, slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)

        if request.GET.get('size'):
            size = request.GET.get('size')
            print(size)

        return render(request, "core/product_detail.html")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

And here's the JavaScript function:

```js
function get_correct_price(size) {
    console.log(size);
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname + `?size=${size}`;
}
```

In my HTML template, I'm calling the JavaScript function with the size parameter:

```html
<button onclick="get_correct_price('{{ s.name }}')">{{ s.name }}</button>
```

However, when I click the button, the size parameter doesn't seem to be passed to the backend. I've verified that the JavaScript function is being called, and the size parameter is logged correctly in the console.

Could you please help me identify why the size parameter is not being received in the backend? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

urls.py:

```py
path("products/",product_list_view,name="product_list"),
path("product/<pid>/",product_detail_view,name="product_detail"),
path("product/<slug>/",get_product,name="product_detail"),
```

In my models.py:

```py
class Size(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code= models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Product(models.Model):
    pid=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="prd",alphabet="abcdef")


    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
    cagtegory=models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True,related_name="category")
    vendor=models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,related_name="product")
    color=models.ManyToManyField(Color,blank=True)
    size=models.ManyToManyField(Size,blank=True)


    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Apple")
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path,default="product.jpg")
    description=RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True,default="This is a product")

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=1.99)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=2.99)

    specifications=RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)


    tags=TaggableManager(blank=True)

    product_status=models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=10,default="In_review")


    status=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    in_stock=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    digital=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    sku=ShortUUIDField(length=10,max_length=100,prefix="sku",alphabet="abcdef")

    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Products"

    def product_image(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="50" height="50"/>'%(self.image.url))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_percentage(self):
        new_price=((self.old_price-self.price)/self.old_price)*100
        return new_price
```

In short:
I simply want that `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/prdeeffeafaec/?size=15inch` from the url it should print `15inch` this

Comment: Does the request reach the django server?

Comment: yes! I am getting the url : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/prdeeffeafaec/?size=12%20inch`

Comment: Show us your urls.py files?

Comment: I edited the things in the question please check it out

Comment: Why do you have `path("product/<slug>/",get_product,name="product_detail")` same name for two urls.

Comment: So what should I do? and I change the name in url but still not working.

Comment: You should make id in int format and slug in slug format.

Comment: please help me out

Comment: Look my answer. I have updated it. 4) part, why do you filter with slug=slug. Your model doesn't have slug field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your url names unique.
2. Make url parameters as below.

```py
path("products/",product_list_view,name="product_list"),
path("product/<int:pid>/",product_detail_view,name="product_detail"),
path("product/<slug:slug>/",get_product,name="get_product")
```

[ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/#example)

3. 

Make an error page template and show this page on exception

```
def get_product(request, slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)

        if request.GET.get('size'):
            size = request.GET.get('size')
            print(size)

        return render(request, "core/product_detail.html")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e) 
        return render(request, "core/error_page.html")
```

4. Obviously, you model have no field called slug. So below code wouldn't work.
   And `print(size)` won't print. It's because below line doesn't work / generate an error.

```py
product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

You can only get objects using fields values in the model.
Like below.

```py
product = Product.objects.get(title="product_title")

#or

product = Product.objects.get(id=4)
```

Comment: If I change my url into `path("product/<int:pid>/",product_detail_view,name="product_detail"),`
I am getting
`ValueError at /product/prdeeffeafaec/
The view core.views.get_product didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
`this error

Comment: As error says. Return response on error.

Comment: I also post my models

Comment: Actually not it is redirecting me to the error page. But it is not printing the `print(size)` this in terminal

Comment: I simply want that ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/prdeeffeafaec/?size=15inch``` from the url it should print ```15inch``` this

Comment: prdeeffeafaec what's that? Title?

Comment: Did you look my answer. Your model doesn't have a slug field.

Comment: Yes I find out the solutions

Comment: Nice. . It was title, right.